# Question on injective-surjective functions, regarding cardinality of domain, codomain

Tags: functions, cardinals

Ok so we know that if *A, B* are finite sets and *f*: *A* to *B* is injective, then cardinality(*A*)≤cardinality(*B*),
 and that the opposite inequality holds for a surjection. My question is, if we know that f is not injective, can we assume that cardinality(*A*)>cardinality(*B*)
 (and similarly for a surjection)? I'm asking this because I need to prove that there is no *f*:*A* to *A* that is either (injective but not surjective) or (surjective but not injective), with *A* finite. Thanks! (Sorry for my bad typing, I can't figure out how to use the symbols)

Comment: Regarding about how to use symbols, just add `$...$`, where `...` means "any math expression". Search for MathJax to see some common commands.

Comment: For what you are trying to prove, given $f$ is injective from $A$ to $A$, then $f$ is a bijection from $A$ to Range($f$), so Range($f$) is a subset of $A$ with the same cardinality as $A$. Since $A$ is finite, ....

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, knowing that you have a non-injective function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ *doesn't* tell you that $|A| > |B|$.  For a counterexample with finite sets, consider the function

$f : \{1, 2, 3\} \rightarrow \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$

defined by:

$f(x) = 1, \forall x \in \{1,2,3\}$.

This function is not injective, since $f(1) = f(2) = f(3)$, but $1 \neq 2$, $2 \neq 3$, and $1 \neq 3$, but $|\{1,2,3\}| < |\{1,2,3,4\}|$.

A good point to keep in mind when thinking about questions like this is that for most sets $A$ and $B$, there are many different possible functions from $A$ to $B$.  Just because you have *one particular function* from $A$ to $B$ that isn't injective, doesn't mean that no function from $A$ to $B$ is injective.  In the above example, we can see that while $f$ is not injective, we can define $g :  \{1, 2, 3\} \rightarrow \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ by $g(x) = x$, and $g$ is in fact injective, showing that $|\{1,2,3\}| \leq |\{1,2,3,4\}|$.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $Y=\mathbb{Z}$ $|\mathbb{Z}| < |\mathbb{R}|$. Consider the function $f:X \to Y$ defined $f(x)=1$ for all $x$. This map is not injective, but, as stated, $|X|<|Y|$.

If you want an example with finite sets $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $Y=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and define the same map. The same issue arises. It is similar when a map fails to be surjective.

As a hint for your problem. Suppose $f:A \to A$ is injective but surjective. So there is in $a \in A$ which does not have a partner. But what happens to $f(a)$?. The idea is similar for the surjective case.

Comment: Yeah I see, I should have noticed that before. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. This stuff can be funny at first.

Comment: If $Y=\{Z\}$ how is $f(x)=1$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ into $Y$? Unless, $Z=1$.

Comment: Just a mistake in notation. All fixed.

Comment: Please upvote/accept answer if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Did you mean to say suppose $f: A \to A$ is injective but **not** surjective?